# ToString in a function

Tags: string-manipulation

```
f[x2_] = ToExpression[StringTake[ToString[x2], -1]] x2;
f[a3]
(*Out: 2 a3*)
```

I expected the output to be `3 a3`, but apparently `x2` isn't evaluated in `ToString`.

How would one construct a function that gives the expected result?

Comment: Use `SetDelayed[]` instead of `Set[]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `SetDelayed` to get the desired behaviour. If you use only set, then to `ToString` just sees x2, which is where the two is coming from.

So this gives the correct result:

```
f[x2_] := ToExpression[StringTake[ToString[x2], -1]] x2;
f[a3]
(* 3 a3*)
```

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html) on `Set` and `SetDelayed`.